# How to backup only a small preview of datomic DB?

Tags: clojure, backup, datomic

I wanted to back-up my datomic DB. I am familiar with the steps defined at https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/backup.html but since the data size is huge (in TBs), I wanted to only backup a small preview of the entire DB, like one or two attribute values from every entity.

Also, if I had that backup present at some location, like S3 or something, is it possible to just copy only a certain part of the entire backup so that it becomes a small preview of the entire DB as described above?

Comment: I would be really surprised, that "sampling" the DB like this would give meaningfull data for e.g. a test environment other than operational purposes like running a datomic DB.  Do you really need "random data" or rather "sane data, but less"? With "just less" you could investigate into backupping just up to a point in time (not that i know about how to do that).